# Looking for simple slideshow with previous and next navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I just need to display the images in the very center of the page. The images will be different widths but should still be centered. I have custom arrow pointers and I want the other images to be hidden while the other fades out and a new one in.

I've found jquery cycle and stuff but I couldn't center the slideshow to the center of the page for some strange reason.

Any advice?

What plugins can I alter (just replace images) to get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Anything Slider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/). That seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.proglogic.com/learn/javascript/lesson10.php

not sure if you are still looking for this, as its been awhile since your post - but this is a very simple slideshow using javascript and a table.  the image is displayed with "previous" and "next" links below, which can of course be changed to whatever you want. the only possible issue is that it uses html tables which are frowned upon (unless completely necessary).  it is however, very easily center-able using css.  good luck!